# How to recover the root password (passwd/chroot not found)?

Tags: debian, root, password-recovery, passwd

I did `init=/bin/bash`, `ctrl-x`, mount of `root`, but when I try to run `chroot` or `passwd` it simply doesn't find any command.

I see many tutorials, but they assume I have passwd and chroot. But I have not? Where are they? I have the $PATH normally configured.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? If you just need to remove the password for root you can do that with a text editor so long as you can write to the password file(s).

Comment: Just to restore the password. You mean remove the password part in /etc/passwd?

Comment: Ah on modern Debian remove the hash from /etc/shadow, yes. You'll need to have your mounts straight first so you can edit shadow which may be the problem you are asking about on SU.

Comment: I think no problem should be with the su, because I login as root from the grub menu -> e -> init=/bin/bash -> ctrl-x

Comment: Ah, sorry for confusion. In that context I meant SuperUser, the site we are on! Making sure you have rw on the filesystem and privileges to write /etc/password and /etc/shadow should suffice.